# Sync Audio and Mouse Movements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash, timer

this seems to be a nearly impossible task, which I am working on the last months.

I am trying to sync my recorded audio with my recorded mouse position movements.

I have tried so many algorithms and looking deeper into javascript timers.

For me I have noticed it is impossible to record mouse and audio and snyc those both elements

with HTML5 Audio, which runs reliable.

The mouse recording using self-adjusting timers is still too crappy to provide a stable

solution. (setTimeout,setInterval,performanceNowKit... etc..)

Is there any way I can sync recorded mouse movements with recorded audio so that there is some

sort of whiteboard I am talking to, because no matter what I do it get´s unsync after a while.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am only guessing but I really think you are SOL. Can you elaborate on what you are doing exactly?

Comment: I am recording mouse coordinates on my HTML site and using flash recorder to record what I am saying at the same time. Afterwards I want to replay what I have recorded.